# XCode 8, some methods disappeared ? ex: layoutAttributesClass() -> AnyClass

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I encounter some issues on collectionView & collectionViewLayout on Xcode 8 + Swift 3 project.

It's seems some methods totally disappeared.

For example, when I subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout:

```
override func layoutAttributesClass() -> AnyClass
```

This trigger xcode error:

```
Method does not override Any Method from his superclass
```

Documentation of this method:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UICollectionViewLayout/layoutAttributesClass

Not sure it's Xcode 8 related because I already have strange issues with collectionView on Xcode 7 and swift 2.3, for example, itemSizeAtIndexPath method is not detected on xcode but if I put the method in a collectionViewController it's called even without the keyword override.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 3, it is a (class) *property* instead of a method:

```
override class var layoutAttributesClass: AnyClass {
    // ...
}
```