# Implement layoutAttributesClass() in Swift 3

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3, xcode8

I am writing a custom Collection View Layout in swift and xcode 8. I tried implementing the custom collection view layout attributes with the following function

```
override class func layoutAttributesClass() -> AnyClass {
    return CircularCollectionViewLayoutAttributes.self
  }
```

But I get error 'Method does not override any method from its superclass'. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode 8, some methods disappeared ? ex: layoutAttributesClass() -> AnyClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447753/xcode-8-some-methods-disappeared-ex-layoutattributesclass-anyclass)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `var` instead of func in **Swift 3**:

```
override class var layoutAttributesClass: AnyClass {
    // ...
}
```